# Check if resource is cached without downloading

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, cdn

It is possible in javascript to check if image or script is in cache without downloading it?

Example of why I want this is using public CDNs. I want to check if user has jquery libs cached from googleapis or from jquery.com or from MS CDN and only if they don't, then waste their bandwidth. Maybe some xhr head request could help me with that?

From answers here, it seems that following code downloads image even without inserting to it DOM.

```
var i = new Image
i.src='image.jpg'
return i.complete
```

And `HTMLScriptElement` doesn't have `complete` property at all.

Comment: No, you can't access cache from js. Just use googleapis, (I think it's the most used one), and let the browser deal with its cache, no need to rewrite it.

Comment: If it is already in the cache, most of the servers will respond with 304 Not modified and no bandwidth will be consumed to transfer files.